# Jupyter lab install noise ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab, noise

I just installed jupyterlab on my pc and installed some requirements. One of those is a `pip install noise` as I need to use `snoise3`

The module get successfully installed, and if I run `pip3 freeze`, I can see it in the list

```
noise==1.2.2
```

After that I started my jupyterlab and at the top I did import all the modules I needed, and one of them is noise, as follow:

```
from noise import snoise3
```

but unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-239189d97387> in <module>
      4 from skimage.draw import polygon
      5 from PIL import Image
----> 6 from noise import snoise3

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'noise'
```

Can please anyone address me on what I am doing wrong here? I google around but I couldn't find any solution to this issue

Comment: In a cell in your notebook, did you try `%pip install noise`? Then restart kernel and try the import statement. I just did that and `from noise import snoise3` ran without any issue. If that works for you, your issue was you are installing your packages in a place that isn't the same as your notebook uses as a source environment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. As I thought, the issue is with my arch. now the error is spitting out this `(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/_perlin.cpython-38-darwin.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/_perlin.cpython-38-darwin.so' (no such file)` I am on a macOs m1